# IpProtocols firefox add-on with gnome-terminal and multiple tabs

Tags: command-line, gnome, firefox, gnome-terminal, telnet

I want to use Firefox with IpProtocols 0.2.3 to launch telnet sessions from browser. It is working well for me with xterm terminal emulator, but i wish to use multiple tabs. Now I try to use gnome-terminal by replacing in the add-on configuration the path to xterm (`/usr/bin/xterm`) with `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` and adding the following argument `-hold -e telnet $1` The problem is that this only work with xterm.
Plus I really want to be opened a new tab for every click to an IP address.

Is there anyone of you guys who successfully use this type of configuration?

Comment: Try `gnome-terminal.wrapper`, it is the compatibility layer for gnome-terminal to replace xterm.

Comment: Cool!
With gnome-terminal.wrapper works great. Now it would be nice if every new session would open in a new tab. I've seen [here](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/pref-tab-window.html.en) that there must be an option that I don't have to open new sessions in tabs. Any idea why I miss that option?

Comment: I couldn't get any way to open tab in `gnome-terminal v3.6.2` from CLI. Is it possible to try `xfce4-terminal.wrapper` with `--tab`?

Comment: @Sneetsher With xfce4-terminal.wrapper does not work. Even with --tab every time opens new instances instead of new tabs.